# how to hide field If image is not available in Datatables using PHP?

Tags: php, image

[image]

I want to hide image field when user not upload image.

```
<tr align="center">
    <td><?php echo $result['id'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result['user_id']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result['username']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result['subject']?></td>
    <td>
    <?
        
    if (file_exists(public_path("images/".$result['image'].""))){
        unlink(public_path("images/".$result['image']."")); {?>
        <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo "images/".$result['image']."" ?>">
        <img src=<?php echo "images/".$result['image'].""?>
        style="height: 150px; width: 150px" /></a>
    <? } }  else {
            echo "Image not available";
    } 
    ?>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $result['question']?></td>
    <td><a href="#?id=<?=$result['id']?>">
    <input type="Button" name="reply" value=Reply id="reply" onclick="togglePopup()" /></a></td>
</tr>
```

When I click on image it redirect me to my image directory.
When I click on image it open in new tab (if image is available) and if image is not available it not open.?
please anyone help me.

Comment: `if (file_exists( .... unlink( ...` If the file exists you delete it?!

Comment: Just tip: This kind of mixing HTML & PHP code makes me sick, sorry... Better prepare variable with image tag before HTML, and then just put it in your HTML marckup. The same about `<td><?php echo $result['id'] ?></td>`, drama.

Comment: `<input>` inside `<a>` ?! Makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<?php if(file_exists("images/".$result['image'])){ ?>
    <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo "images/".$result['image']."" ?>">
        <img src=<?php echo "images/".$result['image']."" ?> style="height: 150px; width: 150px" />. 
  </a>
<?php } else {
    //
} ?>
```

This code check image is available or no

Answer (score 0):

First You have to check it there is a value in `$result['image']`
then check if the image exists in the server `file_exists("images/".$result['image'])`

```
<?php if(isset($result['image']) && file_exists("images/".$result['image'])){ ?>
    <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo "images/".$result['image']."" ?>">
        <img src=<?php echo "images/".$result['image']."" ?> style="height: 150px; width: 150px" />. 
  </a>
<?php } else {
    //
} ?>
```

Comment: Little typo: `$reslut['image']`